# Is inflammation post anaerobic workout desireable?

Tags: exercise, muscle, inflammation

My understanding of how muscle growth works is that anaerobic exercise causes damage to the muscles on the microscopic scale, and this damage triggers — and is subsequently repaired by — a healing process that overcompensates for the damage, making more muscle.

If damage of a certain kind is desireable for muscle growth, but other damage is not and causes injury, which kind is inflammation? Are attempts to reduce inflammation with ice packs, cold showers, or anti-inflammatory drugs detrimental to muscle growth?